# Как при наведении и по щелчку на блоке менять изображение в нём?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок, в котором есть изображение, заголовок и описание.
Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на блок менялась картинка на другую, а по клику на блок, менялась картинка новую?
 Только `CSS` и `HTML`, без скриптов.

```css
.cards {
  display: table;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.card-mg {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
}

.card-padding {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 5% 0 5%;
}

.card .img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.card1 .img {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPzLT.jpg);
}

.card h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 5% 0 5% 0;
}

.card h4 {
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card card1">
    <div class="img">
    </div>
    <div class="card-padding">
      <h1>HEADING</h1>
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non, praesentium.</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Только если input:checked

Comment: @Air, можно, пожалуйста, пример? (

Comment: @Air, Да, я понимаю, я знаю JS, но мне нужно именно без JS. Так бы сразу сделал, без вопросов(((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Учти, что-бы картинки красиво менялись и не растягивались и выглядели нормально, все три разные картинки должны быть одного размера

```css
.cards {
  display: table;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.card-padding {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 5% 0 5%;
}

.card h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 5% 0 5% 0;
}

.card h4 {
  font-weight: 100;
}

label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url(http://discoverbath.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/photo-cascades-golf.jpg);
  transition: background .3s;
}

label:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url(https://fsa.zobj.net/crop.php?r=MdpN4yKJjYB3f7zU024ZnxUSiyf1pnsYBLCVFtIq4sm05-0muXgCH66x2RDuMWf3mHLZHrLoGn5jITRaNtVqyHcohCOSNB1FysLd05AqZ8S4mbktSxPriIRsL_b6_D05VuZOn-Y_Mj-Mn0l4qz8EvvEHQhlxvJy4kZWmQA);
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

input:checked~label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url(http://snipeclass.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-300x220.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card card1">
    <input id="in" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="in"></label>
    <div class="card-padding">
      <h1>HEADING</h1>
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non, praesentium.</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```